# Config elasticsearch with magento 2.1

Tags: magento2

I have a homework in school. I want to install ElasticSearch to improve the search in Magento 2.1 . But don't have any doc guide me to do it. Only have doc in enterprise. 
So, If you know way to do it. Help me.
Thank for your support!

Answer (score 0):

You should follow this project and explore it
[ElasticSuite](https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite)